# domain of attraction for nonlinear system

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have a nonlinear system $x'=Ax+g(x)$ , A is Hurwitz, g is locally Lipschitz and $||g(x)||_2 <= c*||x||_2^2$   , where  $||.||_2$ is the 2-norm (Euklid).
What is a guess for the domain of attraction? 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. Please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.